# Invalid bind expression type of Contact does not match domain of foreign key

Tags: apex

```
public class ContactHandlar {
public static void beforeInsert(List<Contact> conList){
    set<Id> std=new set<Id>();
    for(contact c : conList){
        if(c.AccountId != null){
        std.add(c.AccountId);
        }
    }
    map<Id,contact> maps=new map<Id,contact>([select id,name from contact where AccountId IN : conList]);
    for(Contact c : conList){

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should filter on the collection of account ids, not your input collection of `Contact` records.

Incorrect:

```
WHERE AccountId IN :conList
```

Correct

```
WHERE Accountid IN :std
```

Also worth noting that you could come up with much better variable names than `std`. Try to use complete words and convey information. For instance, I would name this collection `accountIds`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you're trying to match a list of contacts to an AccountId field. This is invalid. Instead, you need to use the variable that gathered all the AccountId values in:

```
map<Id,contact> maps=new map<Id,contact>([
  select id,name from contact where AccountId IN :std]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is on the statement `map<Id,contact> maps=new map<Id,contact>([select id,name from contact where AccountId IN : conList]);`

List `conList` is declared as List of Contact and SOQL is expecting List of `Account` Id

Try changing above line to:`map<Id,contact> maps=new map<Id,contact>([select id,name from contact where AccountId IN : std]);`